# Value 2016-12-14T07%3A11%3A17Z for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I see my Timestamp value is according to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html)

```
Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z
```

But still I'm getting error response saying

> 2016-12-14T07%3A11%3A17Z for parameter Timestamp is invalid.

.

This is my url

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ7NHWB4XOVV6LFEA&AssociateTag=emulya-20&IdType=UPC&ItemId=123&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-12-14T07%3A11%3A17Z&Signature=3cSWzK8%2FGiRZ7ZSug39gNAwGqKqIyIHuKoUiVDRQWzU%3D
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the *exact* URL being transmitted? Might something else be URL-encoding again? (Try it just with the colons instead of `%3A`...)

Comment: `            final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                    uri,
                    String.class);` - That is the url and using restTemplate to send request and according to the documentation query  params has to be encoded

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Have you looked at what's being transmitted on the wire, e.g. using Fiddler or Wireshark?

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, When I use curl it works,  the URL in code  is encoding again so i.e the reason it is responding with  error . Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The spring RestTemplate encodes the url, so instead of using `restTemplate.getForObject(String url, Object.class)`, use `restTemplate.getForObject(java.net.URI uri, Object.class)`

```
        final String url = config.getServiceUrl() + "?" + canonicalize
                + "&Signature=" + signature;
        final URI uri = URI.create(url);
        final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                uri,
                String.class);
```